# Texture Painting on image is not showing up in Blender 2.8

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I am a beginner to Blender. Currently I am following Blender Guru's Donut tutorial. When I tried to do the texture painting , color on the image is not showing up.

[image: No Color Texture Image]

If I zoom in very hard then only the color is showing up.

[image: Zoom In First]

[image: Zoom In Second]

And another problem I am having is event if I am drawing white color in the model some greyish color is getting painted. (I am not sure whether both problems are due to same cause or not).

Please help me out.

Here I am attaching the blend file and the texture files

[Drive Link For Blend File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iawqJPD70Jw5JGRdRmFl5cfBLefaz6dh)

Comment: can you post the .blend? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Looks like you are using a cloud texture as a brush mask, but that your brush color is white. Are drawing into the brown to be brown, or are you trying to get white instead? Check your tutorial, but you might be looking for changing mix modes on your brush and you might need to paint on a new image if it is to be a bump map instead of color map.

Comment: I have added the link to blend file . please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the colour is not showing up is because your image is being obscured by the UV mesh of your model which is crazy high resolution. In order to disable it go to View and uncheck "Display Texture Paint UVs":
[image]

The reason your whites are showing up as grays is because of how light works, your model gets shaded and will only display at full brightness under very strong light (which won't show in deafult Viewport Shading mode). It's normal.
In order to see the true colours on your mesh you can select flat shading for your viewport:
[image]

Also I would highly advise disabling your subsurf modifier for your texture painting, my God that donut mesh lags out my pretty decant laptop. I don't know what kind of PC you have but I'm almost sure you'll get a better expirience without the subsurf on.